# Collapsible Navbar Button Does Not Show The Menus When The Screen Size Is Shrunk

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

For some reason when I shrink the screen size to Tablet or Mobile width the collapsible navbar button is not functioning as intended.

Also on the footer the Social Icons are not displaying the logo correctly.All I see are the Icons but not the logos on them.

```css
.jumbotron {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #F44336;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 100px;
}

body{
    padding:0px;
    z-index:0;
}

.navbar-default {
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
         content must come *after* these tags -->
 <title></title>
 <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/phoenixassets/web-frameworks/bootstrap-social.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron" style="top:15em; width=100%; margin-bottom:0;">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <nav class="navbar-default" style="margin-bottom:0;"">
      <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       </button>
                       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
                       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
                       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
                       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">             
                <div>
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                HONG KONG<br>
                Tel.: +852 1234 5678<br>
                Fax: +852 8765 4321<br>
                Email: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
             </address>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding: 40px 10px;">
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google-plus" href="http://google.com/+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-youtube" href="http://youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    <p align=center>© Copyright 2015 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>


 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-target` is "#navbar", but you don't have an `id="navbar"` anywhere.

http://www.codeply.com/go/N3QNRroUnM

There is also a lot of invalid HTML..

(ie: `<div class="jumbotron" style="top:15em; width=100%; margin-bottom:0;"`)

Comment: It's the same problem on codeply. I having trouble rectifying this.

Comment: You need to give the navbar an id="navbar". Clean up the code and if you still have a problem post another question about the social icons.

Comment: I created a test page on which I manged to fix the Social Icon issue as well as the Collapsible navbar issue. Now I'm planning to use the test page as main project site. I'm posting another question as I'm having a new problem. Please help me on that.